# How can I remove/uninstall ubuntu 13.10 to install another linus distro?

Tags: 13.10

I have Ubuntu 13.10 installed in a laptop but don’t feel very happy with it so I want to try other distros. I know I didn’t do it well because I delete windows at the time of the installation, I was really fed up about the slow it was. I didn’t make any partition while installing ubuntu, it is possible to overwrite the other OS? would any remain any rest of Ubuntu?
Tks

Comment: Why not just install over where ubuntu is....

Answer (score 1):

You can install almost most(if not all), the same way most people install ubuntu 13.10. Make a Pendrive from an USB-stick or burn a installation DVD.

Steps to create a pendrive
S1: Download the ISO of your preffered distro

S2: Create a pendrive using tools such as Universal USB Installer to "mount" the iso on  usb-stick.

S3: plug in the usb-stick

S4: reboot

S5: Select the usb-stick as the "Boot-source" from your BIOS

S6: the rest of the installation will explain itself.(select something like "erase ubuntu 13.10" if it appears)

Steps to burn a dvd
same as pendrive but with the word dvd instead of usb-stick, except for #2 where you will need to burn the iso in a dvd using standard iso-tools.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

- Boot another distro's live cd or usb,but don't install it.Then connect to the `internet`.
- Open the terminal(ctrl+alt+t),run the below command to install `gparted`

  `sudo apt-get install gparted && sudo gparted`

  After gparted opened,format the partition(`Select the partition->Right click on it-> Format to->ext4`)in which you want to overwrite.
- Then install the os to the  formatted ext4 partition(Note ubuntu must be installed to `ext4` partition)

Answer (score 0):

1. Put distro of your choice on USB
2. Reboot
3. Enter boot options at start up.It shows computer logo. For me I press F12 some are F2 . It varys from computer to computer
4. search for your USB
5. hit enter on usb
6. should run from there.

You will have a choice to install or test it out. 
I have Ubuntu 12.10 and didn't like the Unity interface at all. I almost uninstalled , but found out about GNOME and love it. I installed linux mint on my friends computer because he contracted the FBI warning virus since I didn't know how to get it off and he loves it.

Answer (score -1):

Complicadisimo.
Yo instalé UBUNTU en mi PC de escritorio. Me estropeó dos discos rigidos (1). Ahora me quedó la opción de Windows ó UBUNTU y no quiero saber mas nada ni del nombre UBUNTU. Quiero que desaparezca por completo de mi vida.
 (1), UBUNTU, obviamente tiene muchas ventajas y otras desventajas respecto a otros sistemas operativos. Pero la peor desventaja que le veo, es la falta de instrucciones puntuales, concretas y objetivas por parte de quienes lo producen. No me alcanza con que sea open source y gratis si luego, por la falta de instrucción, pierdo datos muy importantes que para recuperarlo me significan tres días de pérdida de mi trabajo, tiempo y mi PC encendida con todos los riesgos que ello supone por cortes de energía y otros riesgos importantes.
Es muy probable, que la pérdida de información haya sido de mi responsabilidad y no de UBUNTU. Sin embargo, si UBUNTU me hubiese enseñado con suficiente claridad de que manera hacer las cosas, me daba la opción de instalarlo bien, ó descartar la idea de LINUX.
Ahora, me obliga a descartar para siempre esa opción y quizás esto sea injusto.

Comment: Askubuntu is an English language site - please translate to ensure you get the best response to your questions